# Laravel 5 - Deal with controller validation and RESTful clients like Postman

Tags: laravel-5, response, validation, postman

I am using laravel's RESTful resource routes and controllers.
I testing my api with PostMan and/or RestClient(firefox)

Everything was fine before I added laravel's controller validation. Now it respond with very strange responses like: `status code 0`, or even executes the code with **not valid** data. Or even shows strange results taken from the database (which are not included to the controller at all).

That's creepy.

For example:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'room_id' => 'required|integer',
        'body' => 'required'
    ]);

    exit; // Stop the process after the validation...

    // ... Logic to STORE the MESSAGE in the database ...
    return response(null, 204);
}
```

This store function must **only** validate the data and respond with an error if validation fails,
**But** when I execute it from PostMan, It returns response with list of all rooms which belongs to this user. This is creepy, I cannot realize why this is happening.

When I use the **`jQuery.ajax()`** method with the same request options, it **works fine**. It validates the data and stores the message in the database.

*Question* : Is there a way to deal with postman?
*Question* : Is PostMan dangerous? Since the server respond with database info (which is not included to the controller responses).

Answer (score 0):

If you take a closer look at laravel's validation document it says that when data is submitted via HTML form,the validate method would redirect you to a previous page and the error would be flashed into the session, if the validation fails. Although, you will be able to access these error messages in your view using the $error variable.  Therefore you will need to submit the data via ajax in-order to get the JSON error message.

Answer (score 0):

When validatioin failed, Laravel needs to know you are sending ajax request or you explicitly want json respond, otherwise it redirects you to previous page.

You can check my answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38478362/6246592