# Laravel validation throwing "NotFoundHttpException" when used in PostMan but works in Angular $http request

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5, ionic-framework

I am creating an API but stuck debugging.

Using this in my controller method:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'project_id' => 'required',
    'content'    => 'required',
]);
```

If I call that route with PostMan I get a not found error return by Laravel's debugging screen.

However the API call works fine when using an Angular (ionic) $http request.

Any help?

Comment: Please add more information. What does your angular code look like? What do your routes look like?

Comment: Its using Postman that is causing the issue as said. If I request the same URL in both angular and Postman it causes that response only if using validation.

Comment: You're not providing enough information. What does the route in your routes.php file look like vs the url being called in postman and angular.

Answer (score 4):

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#form-request-validation
>   If validation fails, a redirect response will be generated to send the user back to their previous location. The errors will also be flashed to the session so they are available for display. If the request was an AJAX request, a HTTP response with a 422 status code will be returned to the user including a JSON representation of the validation errors.

Checkout the code from FormRequest

```
public function response(array $errors)
{
    if ($this->ajax() || $this->wantsJson()) {
        return new JsonResponse($errors, 422);
    }

    return $this->redirector->to($this->getRedirectUrl())
                                    ->withInput($this->except($this->dontFlash))
                                    ->withErrors($errors, $this->errorBag);
}
```

When you use angular, Laravel knows you are sending ajax requests. When using Postman, Laravel thought it's a form request and redirect you to previous page which is 404. The solution is to add a header `Accept: application/json` in postman requests, so that Laravel knows you `wantsJson()` or `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` so Laravel thinks it's a `ajax()` request.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
$validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
   'project_id' => 'required',
   'content'    => 'required',
    ]);

if($validator->fails()){
  return 'Validation error';
}
else{
 return 'No error';
 }
```